# Proof check:$ \left | \mathbb{R} \right |= 2^{\left|\mathbb{N} \right |}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification, cardinals

This is my first time to post here. Sorry if this post is too simple or naive.

Here I would like to prove that $\left | \mathbb{R} \right |= 2^{\left |\mathbb{N}  \right |}$

I would first construct a bijective mapping from $\mathbb{R}$ to [0,1) like this:
$$f(x)=\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{x-2}+\frac{1}{2}&\text{if } x<0\\ 
0&\text{if } x=0\\ 
\frac{1}{x+2} & \text{if } x>0
\end{cases}$$
Sorry this missed the $\frac{1}{2}$. I will fill this 'gap' by mapping $\frac{1}{4}$ to $\frac{1}{2}$, $\frac{1}{8}$ to $\frac{1}{4}$, etc... and the others just keep it.
So now I have $\left | \mathbb{R} \right |= \left | [0,1) \right |$

Consider the binary representation of each element in $[0,1)$. If it has a finite representation, add zero's behind to make it infinite. As the cardinality of the length of each representation equals $\left|\mathbb{N}\right|$, I have $\left|\mathbb{R}\right|=2^{\left|\mathbb{N}\right|}$. Q.E.D.

My question is: is the last part of my proof not clear or strict enough? How can I improve it? Any help or suggestion is appreciated. Thank you! :D

Comment: You are essentially clear and correct. You just have to worry a little bit about things like $1/2 = 0.0111\ldots = 0.100\ldots$.

Comment: @EthanBolker Thank you. Can I fix it like this: consider the set of all representations with infinitely many 1's at the end. The cardinality of this set equals |N| as we can just 'chop' all the 1's at the end and this is a bijective mapping to the set of all finite representations with the last digit is 0. Then |R|=2^|N|+|N| since in my construction ending with zero's is adopted. What should I do next to remove the |N|? Thank you.

Comment: @user3313320 By Cantor's theorem 2^|N|>|N|. Now by cardinal arithmetic we have 2^|N|+|N|=2^|N|.

Comment: @wythagoras Thank you! OMG how can I forget the cardinal arithmetic LOL. Thanks a lot.